# Using method to call for a y/n answer

Tags: java

I have this code. The askToContinue() method is being called to ask the user if they would like to continue but my problem is it just ignores the choice and starts the program again no matter what I enter. What am I missing in the code that is causing it to ignore my choice?

```
public class FutureValueApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Future Value Calculator\n");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        // get the input from the user
        System.out.println("DATA ENTRY");
        double monthlyInvestment = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
                "Enter monthly investment: ", 0, 1000);
        double interestRate = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
                "Enter yearly interest rate: ", 0, 30);
        int years = getIntWithinRange(sc,
                "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);
        System.out.println();

        // calculate the future value
        double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate / 12 / 100;
        int months = years * 12;
        double futureValue = calculateFutureValue(
                monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);

        // print the results
        System.out.println("FORMATTED RESULTS");
        printFormattedResults(monthlyInvestment, 
                interestRate, years, futureValue);
        System.out.println();

        askToContinue(sc);
    }
}

private static void printFormattedResults(double monthlyInvestment, 
        double interestRate, int years, double futureValue){
    // get the currency and percent formatters
    NumberFormat c = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    NumberFormat p = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    p.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
    // format the result as a single string
    String results
      = "Monthly investment:   " + c.format(monthlyInvestment) + "\n"
      + "Yearly interest rate: " + p.format(interestRate / 100) + "\n"
      + "Number of years:      " + years + "\n"
      + "Future value:         " + c.format(futureValue) + "\n";
        System.out.println(results);
  }

public static String askToContinue(Scanner sc){
    // see if the user wants to conti1nue
    System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
    String choice = sc.next();
    System.out.println();
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: You missed a `if-else` test in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Change this

```
askToContinue(sc);
```

to

```
choice = askToContinue(sc);
```

Because you need to **assign** the value returned from `askToContinue` to the local reference named `choice`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the result of askToContinue to the choice variable which is checked in the loop.
Possibly the confusion is the choice variable inside the askToContinue method. Note, this is a different variable and does not affect the choice variable checked in the while statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a variable inside a method, it is not recognized by the code outside of your method, even if it has the same name. So, in your code for example, you have,

```
public static String askToContinue(Scanner sc){
    // see if the user wants to conti1nue
    System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
    String choice = sc.next(); // this choice variable exists only for the 
                               // askToContinue method
                               // Once you assign it over here and return it 
                               // with the code below, you should use the returned 
                               // value to update the variable choice, which is 
                               // defined outside your askToContinue method
    System.out.println();
    return choice;
}
```

So, as the other answers have pointed out, if you do,

```
choice = askToContinue(sc);
```

then the code will run fine since the choice variable defined in the main method will get updated according to the value you input

Answer (score 0):

Based on 
John Camerin's answer,to skip double **`assigning`** in your code, you can make your `choice` variable as global `static` variable by define it in your class :

```
public class FutureValueApp {

public static String choice;

}
```

Or send it as second parameter in your method :

```
askToContinue(sc,choice);
```